# Call to undefined function Phalcon\Image\Adapter\Imagick()

Tags: php, phalcon, imagick

I have:

/etc/php5/conf.d/

30-imagick.ini

90-phalcon.ini

phpinfo:
[image]
[image]

but I get the following error
`

```
Call to undefined function Phalcon\Image\Adapter\Imagick()
```

`On`

```
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Http\Response;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as PdoMysql;
...
$img = Phalcon\Image\Adapter\Imagick('image.png');
$img->resize(366, 366, Phalcon\Image::FIT)->save();
```

`

Answer (score 3):

Though you did not post any code in your question (why not?) I think one can assume that:

You are using namespaces in your Project. Inside a namespace file you refer to class Imagick. That means that php looks for that class *inside the current active namespace*.

instead you have to refer to the class either in the global namespace or in the namespace it is actually defined in. So something like:

```
$img = new \Imagick('image.png');
```

or

```
$img = new \Phalcon\Image\Adapter\Imagick('image.png');
```

*Note the leading back slash (`\`)...*

alternatively you can import the class once at the beginning of your file (see the `use` command in php) and then use it without namescape, since it then exists in your local namespace.

Comment: +1. Yep, now that the OP has added the code, we can see this is the  correct answer. Stick a leading backslash on it. Or better yet, add a `use` statement for that namespace so that you can drop the namespace from the body of the code entirely.

Comment: @mr_nobody Ah, ok, that didn't even occur to me. But now that you mention it: the error message is quite obvious: it claims an unknown function, not an unknown class. LOL